# Image uploader in ajax or Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I want to upload image with the help of ajax or jQuery without page refreshing.
I have lot of images in my web page and when i will click any of them then it will show in image box.
Please help me for this problem i get lot of solution for simple uploading code but i need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AJAX Upload jQuery plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

[Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

Comment: Just for the record, this doesn't contradict my answer - the plugins use an <iframe> behind the scenes :)

Comment: I am using Asp.net is it possible in asp.net

Comment: What are you talking about? Server-Sive language doesn't matter. You can use ajax with every server-side language

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files with AJAX, but you can use an `<iframe>` to make it look as though that's what you're doing...

Just create an `<iframe>` with a simple form inside it (don't forget the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`) and use that to display the file input. When that form is submitted, only the iframe will reload.

Comment: I am using Asp.net is it possible in asp.net

Comment: The server-side technology you use doesn't matter. You could use Flash or Java on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery in your project you don't actually need to do `<iframe>` thing on your own, there are plenty of plugins for it.

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) IMO seems to be the best one.

Comment: I am using Asp.net is it possible in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done directly with ajax due to secutiry reasons, but I have done what you're asking for in an Asp.Net form by following the directions in [this excellent article (link)](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/tony_lombardo/archive/2007/04/09/file-uploads-where-s-the-ajax.aspx)

**HTML**
Make an ASP upload conrol, an iframe and a button to kick off the event

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload" runat="server" CssClass="width100pc"  onchange="submitUpload('UploadFrame', 'PhotoJsonInfo')" />
<iframe src='../Public/blank.htm' name='UploadFrame' style="display:none"></iframe>
<input type="text" id="PhotoJsonInfo" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
```

**Javascript**

```
//Our function expects 2 parameters, the name of the disposable frame
//that we will use for the form post, as well as the id of the input control used to upload the file.
function submitUpload(frameName, uploadId)
{
    document.forms[0].action = window.location;
    //The magic line.. set the target of the form post to be our hidden IFrame
    var defaultFrame = document.forms[0].target;
    document.forms[0].target = frameName;

    //We have to use a setTimeout here so that we can update the document in a separate thread
    //otherwise the document wouldn't update until after the upload completed.
    window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            var uploadControl = $get('<%= this.PhotoUpload.ClientID %>');
            FacebookPreview.onImageUpdating(); //show animated loading gif
            uploadControl.parentNode.replaceChild(uploadControl.cloneNode(true), uploadControl); // not sure this line is neccessary
        }, 100);

    //send request
    document.forms[0].submit();
    // reset postback
    document.forms[0].target = defaultFrame;
 }
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // This is only ever called via an IFrame
        if (PhotoUpload.HasFile)
        {
            // do file saving logic here
            string filePath = "..yourFullFilePathHere";
            PhotoUpload.SaveAs(filePath);

            string fileUrl = ... transform filePath to Url....
            WebHelper.RegisterStartupScript(this, "FileUploaded", String.Format(@"window.parent.OnAfterUpload('{0}');", fileUrl));
        }
    }
}
```